# How to make table display added data without manual refresh

Tags: angular, angular5, crud

I'm building a very crude CRUD application in Angular 5 (It's my first time really using the framework). I have everything working well for the most part.

The table displays the data from a local json server, the modal displays the form, and it accepts the data once submitted. However, the new data doesn't show up after submitting the form unless I do a manual refresh of the page.

What I want it to do is after clicking the "Add Customer" button, the modal closes and the table displays the added record. Below is the main code for the areas in question. I feel I'm right there but I just can't get the final touch.

Please let me know if more details/info is needed.

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  display='none';
  showNew: Boolean = false;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  /*
    1. initiate the customers array
    2. data is fetched from local json server with data storage
    3. results stored in the customers array
    4. function called 

  */
  customers = [];
  fetchData = function() {
   this.http.get("http://localhost:5555/customers").subscribe(
     (res: Response) => {
       this.customers = res.json();
     }
   )

  }

  /* 
   1. Create object
   2. Create function to read form data
  */
  customerObj:object = {};

  addNewCustomer = function(customer) {
    this.customerObj = {
      "firstname": customer.firstname,
      "lastname": customer.lastname
    }
    this.http.post("http://localhost:5555/customers", this.customerObj).subscribe((res:Response) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.showNew = true;
    })
  }

  onCloseHandled(){
    this.display='none';
  }

  openModal(){
    this.display='block';
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
<h1>CUSTOMERS</h1>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor = "let customer of customers">
     <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
     <td>{{customer.firstname}}</td>
     <td>{{customer.lastname}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<div class="text-left">
  <!-- open a modal window by clicking button-->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal()">New</button>
</div>
</div>




<!-- Modal for adding new customer -->
<div class="backdrop" [ngStyle]="{'display':display}"></div>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  [ngStyle]="{'display':display}">

 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

   <div class="modal-content">

     <div class="modal-header">       

       <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Customer</h4>

     </div>

     <div class="modal-body">

       <form id = "formNewCustomer" name = "formNewCustomer" #customerData = "ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "addNewCustomer(customerData.value)">
          <label>First Name</label><input type ="text" name = "firstname" id = "firstname" placeholder="First Name" ngModel><br>
          <label>Last Name</label><input type ="text" name = "lastname" id = "lastname" placeholder="Last Name" ngModel><br>
          <input type="submit" value = "Add Customer">
        </form>


     </div>

     <div class="modal-footer">

       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onCloseHandled()" >Close</button>

     </div>

   </div><!-- /.modal-content -->

 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->

</div><!-- /.modal !-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to re-fetch the data after adding a new customer.

Something like:

```
  addNewCustomer(customer) {
    const customerObj = {
      "firstname": customer.firstname,
      "lastname": customer.lastname
    };

    this.http
      .post("http://localhost:5555/customers", customerObj)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.fetchData())
      ).subscribe((res:Response) => {
        console.log(res);
        // not sure if this.showNew is required? leaving it in for completeness
        this.showNew = true;
      });
  }
```

Note how I'm re-calling fetchMap from inside a switchMap. switchMap just means that after the first observable has come back, switch to a new observable before returning to the subscribe body.

NB - you don't need to use the `function()` syntax on your class functions.

Edit:

And you'll need to refactor your fetchData method here if you are to use this method.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchData().subscribe();
}

// TODO: return array of interfaces, like Customer[]
fetchData(): Observable<[]> {
   return this.http
     .get("http://localhost:5555/customers")
     .pipe(
       // use map to transform the raw http response into a known type
       map(res => res.json())
       // use tap to assign the mapped response to a property
       tap(customers => this.customers = customers)
     );
}
```

The http calls would normally go in some kind of service, returning observables (not subscriptions). You would then subscribe to them in the components.

And it's generally a good idea to deal with interfaces too rather than passing a load of json objects around. That's what the type in typescript is for ;)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm giving it a shot now, but it says can't find name switchMap.

Comment: Ok. sorry, figured that out. I now get the following: on this.fetchData() 

Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<unknown>'.ts(2322)
switchMap.d.ts(3, 50): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to dealing with observables in my services rather than functions that do everything. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I really appreciate the help. One last thing. And I know this is a dumb question, but what am I missing for the form modal to close and clear on submit?

Comment: There's probably a thousand different ways to do modals. At its core though, you've got to think in Angular. Your model will dicate when it opens, and your event handlers will handle some user event that closes it. In your event handler you will update your model to a state that closes the modal. Too much to go into here, but you will probably need at least `*ngIf`, `(click)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Just add this line this.fetchData();


    this.http.post("http://localhost:5555/customers", 
    this.customerObj).subscribe((res:Response) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.showNew = true;
        this.fetchData();
    })
```

Comment: This might technically work, but it's not good practice to set up a new subscription inside another one. It's better practice to use the pipe operators.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your `*ngFor` loop, you need to add tracking:

```
  <tr *ngFor = "let customer of customers; trackBy: someTrackingFunction">
```

(Invent the `someTrackingFunction`, it should unambigously identify a customer - object's ID, for example).

Then, on your post, you can simply add the new customer to the array:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:5555/customers", this.customerObj)
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        const newCustomer = // usually, in REST APIs, res will be the new customer object.

        this.customers = [...this.customers, newCustomer].sort(someOptionalSortingFunction);
```

BTW, do you need to manually call `json()` on response object? That's been deprecated for quite some time. Why not use the (not that new) HttpClientModule?

Comment: I'm just learning things with Angular, so it was just easier for me to create a json file with some data, run a local json server, and pull/update the data in that